# Is there a better way to get custom repeats and ordering for mysql_query() in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm surprised that there isn't already an answer for this... it suggests to me that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Or everyone else is.

Let's say I have an array of possibly repeating values that were sorted client-side coming in as a POST request and the goal is to return a result-set from MySQL indexed by those values and in the same order as those values *and preserving the redundancies*!!!

So, if the values were: 1,2,3,2,3,4,5,5,5

The desired result is:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | one   |
|  2 | two   |
|  3 | three |
|  2 | two   |
|  3 | three |
|  4 | four  |
|  5 | five  |
|  5 | five  |
|  5 | five  |
+----+-------+
```

The code below seems to work, but Christ, seriously? I have to abuse `array_intersect()` and have two different loops, one of them nested, just to make a simple result set get ordered and repeated in the same pattern as the input array? This can't be how it's really supposed to be done.

```
function repQuery($inids,$incol,$querystring,$emptyval = "NULL"){
    # incol is the name of a column in the query
    # inids is an array within which the value of incol must be found
    # querystring is a query of the form...
    # "select FOO from BAR where %s in (%s) BLAH BLAH BLAH"
    # The first %s will be replaced by $incol and the second by $inids
    $qq = mysql_query(sprintf($querystring,$incol,implode(",",$inids))) or die(mysql_error());
    $nf = mysql_num_fields($qq); $dummyrow = array();
    for($ii = 0; $ii < $nf; $ii+= 1){
        $dummyrow[mysql_field_name($qq,$ii)] = $emptyval;
    };
    $out = array_fill(0,count($inids),$dummyrow);
    while($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($qq)){
        foreach(array_keys(array_intersect($inids,array($rr[$incol]))) as $ii) {
            $out[(int)$ii] = $rr;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

My question is: is there some accepted pattern or PHP array command or something else that I'm overlooking? In `R` the above would be a one-liner.

Comment: Maybe "group by id" in mysql query will help?

Comment: It will group all rows that have same id into one. So you will get only one unique id per result set. Or I missed what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yup, I want the opposite of one unique id per result set. I want as many copies of each id as the user requested, in the order they requested.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Yes, porting the code for this is on my list of stuff to do... but, can either MySQLi or PDO accomplish this specific task more concisely, elegantly, or efficiently? Or would it amount to being the same algorithm but using the equivalent MySQLi or PDO functions?

Comment: @f1r3br4nd - Q: You're saying that you want to 1) dynamically generate a SQL query, which 2) searches based on 1, 2 or N (a variable number) of ids.  Correct?  Or are you asking something else entirely?  Please clarify...

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes to 1, and it works. For 2, I mean standard usage of the [IN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function, so if that's what you also mean then yes. The question is about more efficient/concise ways to make the returned results match the original ordering and redundancy of the IDs selected by the user.

Comment: Learning how to use either `mysqli` or PDO should not be on your list of things to do, it should be your **next** thing to do. `mysql_query` is extremely dangerous if not used correctly. What you've done here with `sprintf` obscures some deadly serious SQL injection bugs. A [few examples of proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) show it's not that much more work to do properly and yet will save you immeasurable amounts of pain, suffering or embarrassment in the future caused by SQL injection bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be awesome if it were a feature in MySQL, I don't think there is a way to use `ORDER BY` with a repeating pattern (you can get a "custom pattern" via `ORDER BY FIELD()`, but not quite there).

I'm not sure about any special methods in PHP just for this, but using a temporary array might be able to reduce the headache:

```
function repQuery($inids,$incol,$querystring,$emptyval = "NULL"){
    $qq = mysql_query(sprintf($querystring,$incol,implode(",",$inids))) or die(mysql_error());

    // build a temporary array of all of the results - the row's "ID" is the array index
    $tmpResults = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qq)) {
        $tmpResults[$row['id']] = $row;
    }

    // iterate through the order/list of IDs and insert each result one after the other
    $out = array();
    foreach ($inids as $id) {
        $out[] = $tmpResults[$id];
    }
    return $out;
}
```

This will place every SQL result (one for each ID) in the `$tmpResults` array using the row's ID as the array's index. The next step is to iterate through the `$inids` list, which contains the pattern to replicate, and to insert the corresponding record-result into the `$out` array.

Answer (score 0):

I use PDO and getting the data from the DB is done with PDO below. So don't bother reading if you aren't interested in getting the data via PDO for whatever reason. (I'm not familiar with the mysql_* commands as I use PDO.)

If it were me, I'd make the $inids unique (array_unique) before passing to MySQL and change the SQL statement to include the ID in the SELECT statement.  Something like:

```
select %s, FOO from BAR where %s in (%s)
```

Then the sprintf becomes

```
$tempIds = array_unique($inids);
sprintf($querystring,$incol,$incol,implode(",",array_unique($tempIds)))
```

PDO would be something like

```
$db->prepare(sprintf($querystring,$incol,$incol,implode(",",$tempIds)));
$db->execute(array());
$results = $db->fetchAll();
```

So for your organizational structure I would use something like this:

```
$ids = array();
$srch = array();
foreach ($results AS $key=>$dbData) {
  $ids[] = $dbData['ID'] . ":" . $dbData['FOO'];
  $srch[] = (string) $dbData['ID'];
} 

$out = str_replace($srch, $ids, $inids);
```

I imagine there is a better way to do this but I haven't come up with it yet. This should work assuming that $inids is an array like:

```
$inids = array('1', '2', ...);
```

If the values aren't strings then they will need to be converted into strings before passing to str_replace. Then when you wanted to output them on your page or somewhere you would do this:

```
foreach ($out AS $key=>$str) {
$data = explode(':', $str);
  echo '<br>' . $data[0] . \t . '|' . \t . $data[1];
}
```

Mess with the echo statement as you like.

Comment: Thank you, this will definitely be useful very, very soon. The only reason I accepted the other answer is that's the one I actually put in my code for the this, here-and-now version of the that is due a couple of days from now.

But again, thank you, this will be useful in the future. I wish I could checkbox more than one answer.

Comment: Thanks and no problem. I prefaced my answer regarding PDO because I figured you didn't want to gut what you had in order to replace the mysql_* functions PDO just yet. I chose PDO early on simply because one of the first books I read about MySQL and PHP told me that PDO provided MySQL injection security while the mysql_* functions did not.  Since I didn't have any legacy code to worry about I built myself a DAO based on PDO.  Good luck.